# SQL Error with ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, dashing

```
require 'mysql2'

SCHEDULER.every '2h', :first_in => 0 do |job|

  # MySQL connection
  db = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "host", :username => "username", :password => "password", :port => port, :database => "database" ) 

  sql = "select count(*) from tickets where department_id = 6;"
  tickets_sql = db.query(sql)
  puts tickets_sql

  #Send Events
  send_event('tickets_sql',    {current: tickets_sql})


end
```

I am using the `puts` command so I can see the output in my log file. The output of this command is an error message which is: `#<Mysql2::Result:0x000000025546a8>`

What does this error mean?

I took the same exact query as in the code and ran it on the database and it outputs the number as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an error message, it is an object ([`Mysql2::Result`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mysql2/Mysql2/Result)). You can give `count(*)` and alias (put `as smth` after it) and access as `tickets_sql.first['smth']` (you can use `first` as there is only one row, otherwise you get a collection, so you should iterate through it with `.each`, *for example*, to output retrieved rows with `puts`).

Comment: One more question on this @notulysses lets say that number its returning is a decimal, is there a special way to handle that. count(*) does not seem to work with decimals.

Comment: My apologies for being vague, It shows the decimal, So im using tickets_sql.first['smth']  This returns 0.1942E2 in the code. When i run the query in the database.. the decimal should appear as 19.42 how would you go about getting the decimal place two spots to the right ?

Comment: @Johnathon22: you can cut off unnecessary digits in your sql query